# In springboot,How to store image of my customer in local system and store the image path in the database?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

This is my customer entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;
private String relative;
private String address;
private Long aadhar;
private Long contact;
private String townname;
private String imagePath;
```

this is my controller function to add new customer, i dont know whether i did this corrrectly, i meant to store the imagepath in customer table and images in the custimages folder in static folder,this savCustomer saves the other fields from the form since the form input name and column name are same

```
@PostMapping("/customer/addnew")
public String addNew(Customer customer, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile snapshot) throws IOException {
       if (!snapshot.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                // Generate a random file name
                String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg";
                // Create a File object to save the image
                File file = new File("src/main/resources/static/custimages/" + fileName);
                // Save the snapshot to the file
                snapshot.transferTo(file);
                // Set the imagePath field in the Customer entity
                customer.setImagePath(fileName);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    customerService.saveCustomer(customer);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("addcustomermessage", "added successfully");
    return "redirect:/customer";
}
```

this is my html form

```
    <form class="row g-3" th:action="@{/customer/addnew}"
                            method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label for="image">Upload Image</label> <input type="file"
                                    id="image" name="image" accept="image/*">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-5">
                                        <canvas id="snapshot" width="280" height="200"
                                            style="transform: scaleX(-1)"></canvas>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <button type="button" id="capture" class="btn btn-info">Capture</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-5">
                                        <video id="camera-stream" autoplay width="280" height="200"
                                            style="transform: scaleX(-1);"></video>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label for="aadhar" class="form-label">ஆதார் எண்</label> <input
                                    type="number" min="0" max="999999999999" class="form-control"
                                    id="aadhar" name="aadhar" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <label for="customername" class="form-label">பெயர்</label> <input
                                    type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"
                                    onKeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="relative" class="form-label">S/o,D/o,W/o,C/o</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="relative"
                                    name="relative" onKeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"
                                    required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="contact" class="form-label">தொலைபேசி எண்</label> <input
                                    type="number" min="10" max="9999999999" class="form-control"
                                    id="contact" name="contact" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <label for="inputAddress5" class="form-label">முகவரி</label> <input
                                    type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address"
                                    onKeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"
                                    placeholder="1234 Main St" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label for="inputTown" class="form-label" id="selecttown">ஊர்</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="selecttown" name="townname"
                                    required>
                                    <option selected></option>
                                    <option th:each="town:${towns}" th:value="${town.townname}"
                                        th:text="${town.townname}">...</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>


                            <script>
const constraints = {
        video: true
    };
    const cameraStream = document.getElementById('camera-stream');
    const snapshotCanvas = document.getElementById('snapshot');
    const context = snapshotCanvas.getContext('2d');
    const form = document.querySelector('form');

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
            .then((stream) => {
                cameraStream.srcObject = stream;
            });
    
        

        document.getElementById("capture").addEventListener("click", function() {
               var canvas = document.getElementById('snapshot');
        var video = document.getElementById('camera-stream');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 280, 200);
        canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
          var file = new File([blob], generateFileName(), { type: 'image/jpeg' });
          // Add the file to the form data
          var formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('image', file);
          
        }, 'image/jpeg', 1);
        function generateFileName() {
              var prefix = "customer_";
              var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
              var fileName = prefix + randomNumber + ".jpg";
              return fileName;
            }
    });
</script>

                            <div class="text-center" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mx-1 my-1">Submit</button>
                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary mx-1 my-1">Reset</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

this form has the fields for customer data as well as the first field streams the video inside the form and when i hit the caputre button it took a snapshot and post it as a thumbnail within the form itself , i have a inline code to do these functions, and also it appends the captured snapshot to append it to the image input and once i hit submit my controller function will save the image and the path to the customer table, but the other fields are updated properly in the table, but the image was not uploaded to the custimages folder as well as the imagepath is also null. I am just learning am i doing anything wrong here or am i complicating the code here, instead of easy way.

Comment: First there is no `src/main/resources`, second that isn't the filesystem but the classpath. You cannot store files in the classpath. You need to store them somewhere else like `/var/my-app/images` or whatever path you desire.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the exact answer you're looking for.
But on of the options / solution to store images, you can transform them a base64 image (string format) and store it as a string in your database.

Don't worry about ready the image in your html code because `<img src ="${imgUrl}" >` will understand the base64 format and display it correctly.

I hope this unlocks you

Comment: cool, that means the value i am getting for the input element value="data:base64 (some lengthy random string)" after implementing this  snapshot.toDataURL (this sanpshot is the id of the picture taken) ,is this the base 64 format of the image ? and i can simply save the string to the database table ,this is what you are telling ,correct?

Comment: yes.
Here is how you can transform your image to a base 64 string 
https://www.baeldung.com/java-base64-image-string

Comment: Done ! This works..this can be the one way to implement this requirement ..Thanks!

Comment: Good,
If it works as expected you cam mark the question as answered